# How many Marbles

Tags: combinatorics

A box contains some green marbles and exactly four red marbles. The probability of selecting a red marble is $x\%$. If the number of green marbles is doubled, the probability of selecting one of the four red marbles from the box is $(x - 15)\%$. How many green marbles are in the box before the number of green marbles is doubled?

I thought my answer was correct but it isn't. Can someone help?

At first:

```
 Number of red marbles:  R

 Number of green marbles:  4

 Probability of drawing a red marble:  R / (R + 4)  =  x
```

After doubling the number of green marbles:

```
Number of red marbles:  R

Number of greeen marbles:  8

Probability of drawing a red marble:  R / (R + 8)  =  x - 0.15

  ---   solving this equation for x:         R / (R + 8) + 0.15  =  x
```

Setting the two equations equal to each other:

```
     R / (R + 4)  =  R / (R + 8) + 0.15
```

Multiplying all terms by  (R + 4) · (R + 8)

```
      R · (R + 8)  =  R · (R + 4) + (0.15) · (R + 8) · (R + 4)
```

Multipling out:

```
      R2 + 8R  =  R2 + 4R + 0.15(R2 + 12R + 32)

      R2 + 8R  =  R2 + 4R + 0.15R2 + 1.8R + 4.8
```

Simplifying:

```
                0  =  0.15R2 - 2.2R + 4.8
```

Multiplying by 100:

```
                0  =  15R2 - 220R + 480
```

Dividing by 5:

```
                0  =  3R2 - 44R + 96
```

Factoring:

```
                0  =  (3R + 8)(R - 12)
```

Answers:  either  -8/3 (impossible)  or  12

Comment: In your work, you say the number of red marbles is R, and the number of green marbles is four. But in the problem setup, you say the number of red marbles is four, while the number of green marbles is unknown. I think this is the source of error.

Comment: What @MikeEarnest said.  Kudos to you for spelling out your reasoning in enough detail to allow us to spot the error.